# Zend forms working with ajax/javascript onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework, zend-form

I am writing a code to use `onchange` in my application this is my code so far

```
.Phtml

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function submit()
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        $satellite = intval($_GET['satellite_id']);

        if ($id == 0)
        {
            echo "Please select a Region";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "select * from satellites where region_id = '".$id."'";
            $query = mysql_query($query);
            echo "<select name='satellite_id'><option value=''>-- select one --</option>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                echo "<option value='".$row['satellite_id']."'".($row['satellite_id']==$satellite?" selected":"").">".$row['satellite_name']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            //DisplayFormRow ("Satellite", FormDropDownBox ("satellite_id", $SatelliteARY, $Result['satellite_id']));
        }
    }

    </script

//zend code Form

    $region_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('region_name');
            $region_name->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width: 150px;'));  
            $region_name ->setLabel('Region')
                ->onchange('this.form.submit();') //tried this code ->onchange('javascript:submit();')
                    ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');

            $mdlRegions = new Model_Regions();
            $regions = $mdlRegions->getRegions();       
            foreach ($regions as $region)
            {
                $region_name->addMultiOption($region->region_id, $region->region_name, $region->region_short_name);
            }           
//model

    <?php

    class Model_Regions extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {

        protected $_name = 'regions';
        //protected $_name = 'smmedetails';

        public function getregion($region_id)
        {
            $region_id = (int)$region_id;
            $row = $this->fetchRow('region_id = ' . $region_id);
            if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find row $region_id");
            }
            return $row->toArray();
        }

        public function smmedetails2region($region_name)
        {
            $data = array(
                'region_name'=> $region_name
            );
             return $this->insert($data);
        }

        public function getRegions()
        {
            $select = $this->select();
            return $this->fetchAll($select);
        }


    }

//controller

     public function registerAction()
        {
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js');
            $form = new Form_SmmeDetails();       
            $this->view->form = $form;

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                    $companyname = $form->getValue('companyname');
                    $companytradingname = $form->getValue('companytradingname');
                    $region_name = $form->getValue('region_name');  
                    $satellite_name = $form->getValue('satellite_name');   
                    $city = $form->getValue('city');                   
                    $companyaddress = $form->getValue('companyaddress');               
                    $addresscode = $form->getValue('addresscode');
                    $companypostaladdress = $form->getValue('companypostaladdress');
                    $postalcode = $form->getValue('postalcode');
                    $companyphonenumber = $form->getValue('companyphonenumber');
                    $companyfaxnumber = $form->getValue('companyfaxnumber');
                    $companycellnumber = $form->getValue('companycellnumber');                
                    $businessemailaddress = $form->getValue('businessemailaddress');
                    $businesswebsite = $form->getValue('businesswebsite');


                    $smmedetails = new Application_Model_DbTable_SmmeDetails();
                    $smmeid = $smmedetails ->smmedetailsSmmeDetails($companyname, $companytradingname, $region_name, $satellite_name, $city, $companyaddress, $addresscode, $companypostaladdress, $postalcode, $companyphonenumber, $companyfaxnumber, 
                    $companycellnumber, $businessemailaddress, $businesswebsite);


                    // $region = new Application_Model_DbTable_Region();
                     //$region ->smmedetails2region($formData, $smmedetails->smmeid);




                    $this->_redirect('/admin/smme/register2/smmeid/'.$smmeid);
                } else {
                    $form->populate($formData);
                }

        }
        }
```

The code is suppose to view a hidden input select, called satellite when you select a feild option from regions, the satellite should view certain options based on the region selected. In short the region selected should correspond with what the user selected. eg Province is Gauteng, so cites would be, Johannseburg,Pretoria etc. Take note the region and satellite options are called from the database table according to they names and id. The code above keeps giving me and error Message: Method onchange does not exist. Was told not to use onchange method should I be using ajax and can I use javascript and sqlquery in the view or should I call it as an action? If so how? Here is a slight picture example.
[image]

Please be of help

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have more details to add to your previous question, please edit it instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a few suggestions to what you have there.

Firstly, for simplicity, I'd not use the onChange function, because I don't see it [in the API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/), plus JavaScript or jQuery written in that way can become difficult to maintain and write properly. It is a lot simpler to instead include an external JavaScript file. By doing this, you can also test and debug the JavaScript separately, as well as reuse it.

Have a look at the excellent document for [onChange](http://api.jquery.com/change/), and [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). I've used these and others and they're quite straight-forward. For testing, I recommend [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) for starters. It makes testing a breeze.

Secondly, if you're using the Zend libraries for `Model_Regions` and `$region_name`, then I'd suggest using them instead of the direct mysql calls as well. This will allow you to build a good library which you can continue to expand as needed, plus it makes composing SQL quicker and safer.

For the controller, I'd suggest a `RestController` with a `Restful` Route. [Here's an excellent tutorial](http://codeinchaos.com/post/3107629294/restful-services-with-zend-framework-part-1).

I hope this helps you out with the problem. If you need anything more, let me know.

Comment: please check below for my answer still need a bit of help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for emailing me about this.
The way I go about this is as follows:

Firstly I set up the form, and then an action in a controller.
Lets say getmajorgroupAction()
which in that action I would then disable layout, and just get the relevent results based on the id.
Then in the view file, loop through the

so the output from that call would be

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

etc

Personally I use jquery now, whereas the post you referenced when you emailed me, I was using another method.
trying to use something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#division").change(function () {var division =  jQuery("#division").val();
jQuery("#major_group").load("/module/getmajorgroup/", {division_id: division} );});
});
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: please check below for my answer still need a bit of help

Comment: sorry on the delay getting back to you. I should have an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that was useful but i found a way to do it using this formula below, but everytime I click on the first select the while still in the session the second select appears all the time, eg if a person choose the wrong selection and re tried it brings up another field instead of fixing the field. I think its in a countinous loop . heres my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#region_name").on('change', function () {
                ajaxAddField();
            }
        );
        }
    );

    // Retrieve new element's html from controller
    function ajaxAddField() 
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/admin/ajax/get-cities/city/' + encodeURIComponent($('#region_name').val()),
            success: function(newElement) {
            // Insert new element before the Add button
            //$(this).prev().remove().end().before('#city-label');
            $("#city-label").before(newElement);
            }
        }
        );
    }
</script>
```